# JavaScript "callbacks" across redirecting / after reloading

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I've got a site (asp.net mvc razor) on which some functionalities require authorization / login.
These functionalities can be started by clicking on a button for example.
By clicking on such a button, the system checks whether the user is logged in or not.
If not, the user is redirected to the login page where he can sign in.
After that he will be redirected to the initial page again without initiating the users action.

So here's the workflow:

->Page x -> button y -> click -> redirect to login -> login -> redirect to x.
The redirects are simple `Url.Action()` statements.

What I want to do is to dynamically redirect to the page the click came from and ideally jump to the senders selector in order to simplify things for users.

What possibilities do I have to achieve this?
Only things coming to my mind are quite ugly stuff using `ViewBag` and `strings`

Update:
Info: As storing session variables causes problems concerning concurrent requests this feature is disabled solution wide so I cannot use session variables.
Besides: One of the main problems is, that I cannot sign in without making an ajax call or sending a form. And by sending a form or making an ajax call I loose the information about the original initiator of the action and the parameters.
I solved this by adding by adding this to all such actions in their controllers:

```
    [HttpPost]
    
            public ActionResult ActionA(Guid articleId, Guid selectedTrainerId)
            {
            
                //if user is not authenticated then provide the possibility to do so
                if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var localPath = this.ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url?.LocalPath;
                    var parameter = this.ControllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["offeringRateId"];
    
                    var returnUrl = localPath + "?articleId=" + parameter;
    
                    
                    return PartialView("LoginForOfferingPreview", new LoginForOfferingPreviewViewModel
                    {
                        RequestUrl = returnUrl,
                        //this will be used in the view the request was initiated by in order to repeat the intial action (after login has been successfull)
                        Requester = OfferingPreviewRequester.CourseTrialAdd,
                        //this will be used in the view to initiate the request again
                        RequestParameters = new List<dynamic> { new { articleId = articleId },new { selectedTrainerId = selectedTrainerId }}
                    });
    
    
                }
    
                //actual action
                SendBasketEvent(new CourseAddMessage
                {
                    BasketId = BasketId,
                    OfferingRateId = articleId,
                    
                    SelectedTrainerId = selectedTrainerId,
                    SelectedTime = selectedTime,
                    Participants = selectedParticipants,
                    CurrentDateTime = SlDateTime.CurrentDateTimeUtc(SlConst.DefaultTimeZoneTzdb),
                    ConnectionId = connectionId
                }, connectionId);
    
    
                return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse());
            }


the hereby returned view for login contains following js code that is called if the login has been succesfull:


    function onLoginFormSubmit(data) {
     //serialize form containing username+pw
        var datastring = $("#loginForm").serialize();
    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Login_Ajax","Account",new {area=""})',
            data: datastring,
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
// display model errors if sign in failed
                if (!!!data.Success) {
                    $(".buttons-wrap").append('<span id="loginFormError" style="color:red;"></span>');
                    $("#loginFormError").append(data.ErrorMessage);
                   
                }
      
    //call method of initiating view that will decide what to dow now
                if (data.Success) {
                    var parametersObjectAsString = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.RequestParameters))'); 
                    window.onLoginForOfferingPreviewSuccess('@Model.RequestUrl', parametersObjectAsString, '@((int)Model.Requester)');;
                }
       
              
    
            },
            error: function () {
            
               
            }
        });
    
    }
```

this works fine as long signing does not fail due to wrong username or pw.
If that happens, the view shows the errors but by now signing in again something really strange happens:
At first it seems to work exactly like signing in successfully by the first time but then the ajax calls in window function `onLoginForOfferingPreviewSuccess` will always reach the error block without being able to tell you why.
Fiddler reveals weird http response codes like 227,556 or something.

Comment: use sessionStorage or localStorage to store the url of the page the user was on when he clicked the button causing the redirect to the login page.

Comment: The canonical way of doing this would be to pass a redirect URL through as a query string parameter and read it on the payment post. Be sure to validate that it is a valid URL on your site, though.

Comment: You could alternatively have the login as a dialog, rather than redirecting to a different page.

Comment: yeah but this does not really help me because I cannot wait for the sign in to succeed in the initiating method. after signin in the method which triggered the sign in an all its parameters are lost